# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for DecisionPointDictionaryFinder

Tags: java, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, oracle-rules

I have ADF project using JDeveloper and I am using Oracle rules to define my rules.
But `DecisionPointDictionaryFinder` can not load in the following line of code:

```
DecisionPointDictionaryFinder dictionaryFinder = new DecisionPointDictionaryFinder(null);
```

In the following code snippet:

```
public void loadRuleDictionary() throws SDKException, Exception {

    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try {

        reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(getFile()), "UTF-8"));

        DecisionPointDictionaryFinder dictionaryFinder = new DecisionPointDictionaryFinder(null);
        diccionariReglas = RuleDictionary.readDictionary(reader, dictionaryFinder);

        List<SDKWarning> warnings = new ArrayList<SDKWarning>();
        List<SDKException> exceptions = new ArrayList<SDKException>();
        diccionariReglas.validate(exceptions, warnings);
        diccionariReglas.update(warnings);

    } finally {
        if (reader != null) { 
            reader.close(); 
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following exceptions in the log:

```
oracle.jbo.JboException: JBO-29000: It has obtained an unexpected exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError, message=oracle/rules/sdk2/decisionpoint/DecisionPointDictionaryFinder
    at oracle.jbo.pool.ResourcePool.createResource(ResourcePool.java:599)
    at oracle.jbo.common.ampool.ApplicationPoolImpl.prepareApplicationModule(ApplicationPoolImpl.java:2473)
    at oracle.jbo.common.ampool.ApplicationPoolImpl.doCheckout(ApplicationPoolImpl.java:2347)
    at oracle.jbo.common.ampool.ApplicationPoolImpl.useApplicationModule(ApplicationPoolImpl.java:3246)
    at oracle.jbo.common.ampool.SessionCookieImpl.useApplicationModule(SessionCookieImpl.java:572)
    at oracle.jbo.http.HttpSessionCookieImpl.useApplicationModule(HttpSessionCookieImpl.java:234)
    at oracle.jbo.common.ampool.SessionCookieImpl.useApplicationModule(SessionCookieImpl.java:505)
    at oracle.jbo.common.ampool.SessionCookieImpl.useApplicationModule(SessionCookieImpl.java:500)
    at oracle.jbo.client.Configuration.getApplicationModule(Configuration.java:1609)
    at oracle.jbo.client.Configuration.createRootApplicationModule(Configuration.java:1514)
    at oracle.jbo.client.Configuration.createRootApplicationModule(Configuration.java:1485)
    at ad.govern.viator.application.ov.controller.backing.security.Login.getService(Login.java:359)
    at ad.govern.viator.application.ov.controller.backing.security.Login.entrar(Login.java:110)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.MethodExpressionMethodBinding.invoke(MethodExpressionMethodBinding.java:46)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXCommand.broadcast(UIXCommand.java:190)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:475)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:756)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._invokeApplication(LifecycleImpl.java:889)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:379)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:194)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:205)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:106)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:446)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:446)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:271)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:177)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at ad.govern.viator.application.ov.controller.security.SessionTimeoutFilter.doFilter(SessionTimeoutFilter.java:63)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:119)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:442)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:103)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:171)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:139)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/rules/sdk2/decisionpoint/DecisionPointDictionaryFinder
    at ad.govern.viator.application.common.utilitats.DiccionariReglas.loadRuleDictionary(DiccionariReglas.java:111)
    at ad.govern.viator.application.bo.module.administracio.gestio.riscos.GestioRiscosModuleImpl.<init>(GestioRiscosModuleImpl.java:89)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at oracle.jbo.server.ComponentObjectImpl.createRef(ComponentObjectImpl.java:217)
    at oracle.jbo.server.ApplicationModuleImpl.createApplicationModuleImpl(ApplicationModuleImpl.java:4223)
    at oracle.jbo.server.ApplicationModuleDefImpl.loadApplicationModule(ApplicationModuleDefImpl.java:859)
    at oracle.jbo.server.ApplicationModuleDefImpl.loadComponents(ApplicationModuleDefImpl.java:937)
    at oracle.jbo.server.ApplicationModuleImpl.createApplicationModuleImpl(ApplicationModuleImpl.java:4241)
    at oracle.jbo.server.ApplicationModuleDefImpl.loadApplicationModule(ApplicationModuleDefImpl.java:859)
    at oracle.jbo.server.ApplicationModuleDefImpl.loadComponents(ApplicationModuleDefImpl.java:937)
    at oracle.jbo.server.ApplicationModuleImpl.createRootApplicationModule(ApplicationModuleImpl.java:493)
    at oracle.jbo.server.ApplicationModuleHomeImpl.create(ApplicationModuleHomeImpl.java:87)
    at oracle.jbo.common.ampool.DefaultConnectionStrategy.createApplicationModule(DefaultConnectionStrategy.java:158)
    at oracle.jbo.common.ampool.DefaultConnectionStrategy.createApplicationModule(DefaultConnectionStrategy.java:73)
    at oracle.jbo.common.ampool.ApplicationPoolImpl.instantiateResource(ApplicationPoolImpl.java:2913)
    at oracle.jbo.pool.ResourcePool.createResource(ResourcePool.java:580)
    ... 65 more
```

I tried to obtain the libraries of oracle rules in the classpath and everything but to no avail. the thing is that the class file is right there and there is no error at compile time whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar Error `"oracle/adf/share/security/authorization/PermissionClassDescriptor"`

I have resolved this by replacing jar files in `oracle.adf.security(C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\modules\oracle.adf.security)`

Below is the complete error message.

```
 Uncaught exception
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
   oracle/adf/share/security/authorization/PermissionClassDescriptor
  j.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
  j.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
  j.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2128)
  j.a.Component.isCoalesceEventsOverriden(Component.java:6210)
  j.a.Component.access$500(Component.java:186)
  j.a.Component$3.run(Component.java:6164)
  j.a.Component$3.run(Component.java:6162)
  j.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  j.a.Component.checkCoalescing(Component.java:6161)
  j.a.Component.<init>(Component.java:6130)
  j.a.Container.<init>(Container.java:281)
  jx.s.JComponent.<init>(JComponent.java:588)
  jx.s.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:82)
  jx.s.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:109)
  jx.s.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:117)
  o.adfdtinternal.model.ide.security.panel.SecurityPanel.<init>(SecurityPanel.java:111)
  o.jbo.dt.jdevx.ui.editors.common.security.JesSecurity.<init>(JesSecurity.java:37)
  o.jbo.dt.jdevx.ui.editors.entity.EoeNamePage.jbInit2(EoeNamePage.java:71)
  o.jbo.dt.jdevx.ui.editors.entity.EoeNamePage.<init>(EoeNamePage.java:55)
  o.jbo.dt.jdevx.ui.editors.entity.EoeEditor.createNamePage(EoeEditor.java:93)
  o.jbo.dt.jdevx.ui.editors.common.JeoPagedEditor.init(JeoPagedEditor.java:88)
  o.jbo.dt.jdevx.ui.editors.common.JeoPagedEditor.<init>(JeoPagedEditor.java:73)
  o.jbo.dt.jdevx.ui.editors.entity.EoeEditor.<init>(EoeEditor.java:49)
  o.jbo.dt.jdevx.ui.editors.JeoEditor.getGUI(JeoEditor.java:408)
  o.jbo.dt.jdevx.ui.editors.JeoEditor.getPanel(JeoEditor.java:548)
  o.jbo.dt.jdevx.ui.editors.JeoEditor.setContext(JeoEditor.java:630)
  com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.editor.EditorState.createEditor(EditorState.java:169)
  com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.editor.EditorState.getOrCreateEditor(EditorState.java:103)
  com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.editor.SplitPaneState.canSetEditorStatePos(SplitPaneState.java:257)
  com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.editor.SplitPaneState.setCurrentEditorStatePos(SplitPaneState.java:220)
  com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.editor.TabGroupState.createSplitPaneState(TabGroupState.java:113)
  com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.editor.TabGroup.addTabGroupState(TabGroup.java:116)
  com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.NbEditorManager.createEditor(NbEditorManager.java:556)
  com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.NbEditorManager.createEditor(NbEditorManager.java:533)
  com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.NbEditorManager.openEditor(NbEditorManager.java:401)
  o.ii.navigator.OpenEditorController.whenOpenEditor(OpenEditorController.java:55)
  o.ii.navigator.OpenEditorContextMenuListener.handleDefaultAction(OpenEditorContextMenuListener.java:52)
  o.i.controller.ContextMenuListenersHook$LazyContextMenuListener.handleDefaultAction(ContextMenuListenersHook.java:234)
  o.i.controller.ContextMenu.fireDefaultAction(ContextMenu.java:480)
  o.ii.explorer.BaseTreeExplorer.fireDefaultAction(BaseTreeExplorer.java:1852)
  o.ii.explorer.BaseTreeExplorer.dblClicked(BaseTreeExplorer.java:2210)
  o.ii.explorer.BaseTreeExplorer.mouseReleased(BaseTreeExplorer.java:2239)
  o.ii.explorer.CustomTree.processMouseEvent(CustomTree.java:215)
  j.a.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
  j.a.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
  j.a.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
  j.a.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
  j.a.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
  j.a.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
  j.a.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
  j.a.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
  j.a.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
  j.a.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
  j.a.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
  j.a.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
  j.a.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
  j.a.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
  j.a.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
  j.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  j.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
  j.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
  j.a.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
  j.a.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
  j.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  j.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
  j.a.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
  o.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper._dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:169)
  o.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper.dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:151)
  j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
  j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
  j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
  j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
  j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
  j.a.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.adf.share.security.authorization.PermissionClassDescriptor cannot be found by oracle.adfdtinternal.adf-security-dt_12.2.1
  org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
  org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
  org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
  org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
  org.netbeans.modules.netbinox.NetbinoxLoader.loadClass(NetbinoxLoader.java:81)
  j.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  j.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
  j.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
  j.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2128)
  j.a.Component.isCoalesceEventsOverriden(Component.java:6210)
  j.a.Component.access$500(Component.java:186)
  j.a.Component$3.run(Component.java:6164)
  j.a.Component$3.run(Component.java:6162)
  j.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  j.a.Component.checkCoalescing(Component.java:6161)
  j.a.Component.<init>(Component.java:6130)
  j.a.Container.<init>(Container.java:281)
  jx.s.JComponent.<init>(JComponent.java:588)
  jx.s.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:82)
  jx.s.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:109)
  jx.s.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:117)
  o.adfdtinternal.model.ide.security.panel.SecurityPanel.<init>(SecurityPanel.java:111)
  o.jbo.dt.jdevx.ui.editors.common.security.JesSecurity.<init>(JesSecurity.java:37)
  o.jbo.dt.jdevx.ui.editors.entity.EoeNamePage.jbInit2(EoeNamePage.java:71)
  o.jbo.dt.jdevx.ui.editors.entity.EoeNamePage.<init>(EoeNamePage.java:55)
  o.jbo.dt.jdevx.ui.editors.entity.EoeEditor.createNamePage(EoeEditor.java:93)
  o.jbo.dt.jdevx.ui.editors.common.JeoPagedEditor.init(JeoPagedEditor.java:88)
  o.jbo.dt.jdevx.ui.editors.common.JeoPagedEditor.<init>(JeoPagedEditor.java:73)
  o.jbo.dt.jdevx.ui.editors.entity.EoeEditor.<init>(EoeEditor.java:49)
  o.jbo.dt.jdevx.ui.editors.JeoEditor.getGUI(JeoEditor.java:408)
  o.jbo.dt.jdevx.ui.editors.JeoEditor.getPanel(JeoEditor.java:548)
  o.jbo.dt.jdevx.ui.editors.JeoEditor.setContext(JeoEditor.java:630)
  com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.editor.EditorState.createEditor(EditorState.java:169)
  com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.editor.EditorState.getOrCreateEditor(EditorState.java:103)
  com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.editor.SplitPaneState.canSetEditorStatePos(SplitPaneState.java:257)
  com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.editor.SplitPaneState.setCurrentEditorStatePos(SplitPaneState.java:220)
  com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.editor.TabGroupState.createSplitPaneState(TabGroupState.java:113)
  com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.editor.TabGroup.addTabGroupState(TabGroup.java:116)
  com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.NbEditorManager.createEditor(NbEditorManager.java:556)
  com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.NbEditorManager.createEditor(NbEditorManager.java:533)
  com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.NbEditorManager.openEditor(NbEditorManager.java:401)
  o.ii.navigator.OpenEditorController.whenOpenEditor(OpenEditorController.java:55)
  o.ii.navigator.OpenEditorContextMenuListener.handleDefaultAction(OpenEditorContextMenuListener.java:52)
  o.i.controller.ContextMenuListenersHook$LazyContextMenuListener.handleDefaultAction(ContextMenuListenersHook.java:234)
  o.i.controller.ContextMenu.fireDefaultAction(ContextMenu.java:480)
  o.ii.explorer.BaseTreeExplorer.fireDefaultAction(BaseTreeExplorer.java:1852)
  o.ii.explorer.BaseTreeExplorer.dblClicked(BaseTreeExplorer.java:2210)
  o.ii.explorer.BaseTreeExplorer.mouseReleased(BaseTreeExplorer.java:2239)
  o.ii.explorer.CustomTree.processMouseEvent(CustomTree.java:215)
  j.a.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
  j.a.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
  j.a.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
  j.a.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
  j.a.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
  j.a.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
  j.a.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
  j.a.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
  j.a.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
  j.a.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
  j.a.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
  j.a.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
  j.a.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
  j.a.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
  j.a.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
  j.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  j.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
  j.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
  j.a.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
  j.a.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
  j.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  j.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
  j.a.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
  o.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper._dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:169)
  o.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper.dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:151)
  j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
  j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
  j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
  j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.`enter code here`java:101)
  j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
  j.a.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)'
```